# Amarok on Ubuntu 9.10 rapidly skipping tracks

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, audio, media-player, amarok

Subject really says it all. When I try to click on any track, Amarok rapidly moves through the playlist, pulling external information (wikipedia etc) for each song, but not playing it. I feel like it might be a problem with my sound card or driver or something, but all other media players work fine. I can play sounds from within Amarok when I test different sound devices (they all play). I removed the program and re-installed it and still no luck. Any ideas?

Solved: http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=115&t=86535&p=151180#p151180

Comment: First thing I would do is launch Amarok from the command prompt and see if it is outputting any error messages when it skips the tracks.

Comment: No error message when it skips tracks

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like the codecs are missing.

Comment: Would I need to install a codec especially for amarok? VLC plays everything fine, along with Rhythm Box, Banshee, and Listen

Comment: Add community restricted, no change

Comment: @Bobby: I would +1 but I just used my last vote on the question itself :-) I'm 99% sure you're right though.